# Configure multiple Credentials Manager in Concourse

Tags: concourse

Is it possible to configure more than one active credentials provider, for instance Vault and AWS SSM together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

Additional work on Concourse credential managers, encompassing also the use case of having more than one at the same time, is tracked in the [Concourse RFC 5](https://github.com/concourse/rfcs/issues/5).